# Javascript: Why isn't my javascript running both animations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm working on a video game for my project and i'm running into a animation problem. Basically i'm doing a Final Fantasy style game where your recharging your ATB bar and once its full, you can do a skill. So I have 3 functions here. The first one is clearing my ATB bar so that it resets. This code works. The second one is refilling the time-bar by moving a DIV block into place. This works as well. The third function is my attack skill function, which also works except for the fact that it does not do both of these animation functions in the order I placed them.

If you look below, you'll notice I have the code to first run the clear ATB function, and then run the time bar function, hoping that every time I click the button it would reset my ATB. The problem is, it completely ignores the FIRST function and runs the second one. I tried switching them and same thing occurs. So basically I'm stuck where my code will always ignore the first one and operate the 2nd one if both of my animation functions are in the code. So now I'm confused on how to fix this because I want BOTH codes to work. They work separately and independently as it stands now, but when I combine them, only the 2nd one registers.

```
   // 5. ATB TIMEBAR FUNCTION

function clearTimeBar (el, color) {  //Clears the bar
    var elem = document.getElementById(el);
    elem.style.transition = "width 0.0s, ease-in 0s";
    elem.style.background = color;
    elem.style.width = "0px"
}
function timeBar (el, color) {  // Runs the animation
    var elem = document.getElementById(el);
    elem.style.transition = "width 6.0s, ease-in 0s";
    elem.style.background = color;
    elem.style.width = "289px";
    }

// ATTACK SKILL
document.getElementById("attack").addEventListener('click', function(){
    clearTimeBar('overlay','white');  // Clear the ATB bar
    timeBar('overlay', 'blue'); // Run the ATB bar
    var criticalRoll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    var precisionRoll = Math.floor(Math.random() * cs.precision + 1);
    var npcParryRoll = Math.floor(Math.random() * dragonstats.parry + 1);
    var damage = Math.floor(Math.random() * cs.strength + 1);
        if (precisionRoll < npcParryRoll) {
            addMessage("The Dragon evaded your attack!");
            return;
        }
        if (cs.critical >= criticalRoll) {
            damage *= 2;
            damage -= dragonstats.armor;
            dragon.hp -= damage;
            document.getElementById("npchp").innerHTML = dragon.hp;
            addMessage("Critical Strike! Dragon suffers " + damage + " hp!")
            }   
        else if (damage - dragonstats.armor <= 0) {
            addMessage("Your opponents armor withstood your attack!");
            }
    else {  
    damage -= dragonstats.armor;
    dragon.hp -= damage;
    document.getElementById("npchp").innerHTML = dragon.hp;
    addMessage("You hit the dragon for " + damage + " hp!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your timeBar function after the clearTimeBar has completed taking place.

```
window.setTimeout(function() { timeBar('overlay', 'blue') }, 1000/60);
```

or

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(function() { timeBar('overlay', 'blue') });
```